# Check if Appcelerator locale database exists

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I need to know if a locale appcelerator/titanium database exist in an app to be able to migrate data from that DB to ArrowDB.

Is there any way of finding out if a DB exist by its name?

I tried following this answer but didn't succeed.
https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/143890/check-if-local-database-already-exists

// SDK 5.5.0 GA. iOS & Android

Comment: "didn't succeed" is quite broad. What is the issue exactly? How does your code look like?

Comment: I agree:) I just got a string in return regardless if the database existed or not. See my answer for my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this in my index.js as i find it to be a reliable option.

```
var db = Ti.Database.open("workoutsDB");
try {
  var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM workouts ORDER BY date DESC');
  rows.close();
  //If this code block runs the local database exist.
  Alloy.Globals.localDatabaseDoesExist = true;
}
catch (error) {
  //Gives an sql error when the table does not exist
  Alloy.Globals.localDatabaseDoesExist = false;
}
db.close();
```